# How to extend a given set to be a basis of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is the question I am on.

> Let $V=\mathbb{R^5}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let
>   $U=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)\in \mathbb{R^5}|a_1+2a_2+a_3+a_5=0\}$.
>
> Let $u_1=(1,-1,1,0,0)$ and $u_2=(0,0,-1,0,1)$. Find vectors
>   $v_1,...,v_k\in U$ such that $\{u_1,u_2,v_1,...,v_k\}$ is a basis for
>   $U$.

Here is what I have done:

We know we can extend the set to form a basis by simply adding a vector that is not in the span of $u_1,u_2$ such a vector would be $v_1=(0,0,0,1,0) \in U$ now we know $\{u_1,u_2,v_1\}$ are a linearly independent set of vectors. My question is now how to proceed. My instinct is telling me that $U$ is a $4$ dimensional subspace but I'm still not sure on how to proceed. I either need to show $\{u_1,u_2,v_1\}$ spans $U$ or find another vector not in the span of $\{u_1,u_2,v_1\}$ both of which I'm finding tricky.

Any help?

Comment: Just see that (1,-1,1,0,0),(0,0,-1,0,1), (0,0,0,1,0) and (0,0,0,0,1) plugged row-wise will give an echelon form of a matrix having rank 4.

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: Do you know echelon form of a matrix gives rank?

Comment: No I did not sorry could you explain further pleasE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try finding other solutions to the original condition and seeing if they a linearly independent.

For example, $a_1=2, \, a_2=-1 $ may be a solution.

Comment: So we just try to guess a vector that isn't in the span of $\{u_1,u_2,v_1\}$ ?

Comment: In order to find a fourth linearly independent vector, yes. After that you can use row reduction of a matrix of these vectors to show they are linearly independent.

Comment: Yeah although that is not strictly necessary is it since isn't there a theorem that guarantees that the would be LI?

Comment: A sequence of $n$ vectors is linearly independent if $ a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n=0$ implies $a_1=...=a_n=0$. It's just that row reduction is an easy way to prove this, or at least demonstrate it to yourself

Comment: Found the theorem and answered the question now thanks.